What are these white little popcorn-like lumps on my kangaroo paw?
It's winter here in Australia, and the stems of my kangaroo paws have recently sprouted about half a dozen of these weird pure white lumps maybe 5 mm in a diameter.  They're hard and pop off easily when pinched, resembling a piece of popcorn. What are they, and should I worry about them?


My first guess would be some kind of spider egg sac, but the plant is not particularly spider-infested and the egg sacs I've seen before were near/in an obvious spider nest and much more squishy.

This looks like wax scale see attached link to help resolve this:

https://plantdoctor.co.nz/problem-finder/waxy-scale/
